# Hive: changing mapper and reducer memory leads to hugh difference on resource usage

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce

I am quite confused with the 2 parameters:

```
mapreduce.map.memory.mb
mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb
```

At the beginning, I setup them to both **1 GB** then I run many Hive tasks in parallel and I can see all nodes' cpu usage reach above `95%` and memory usages are about 50%.

However, when I run some tasks it may occur:

```
Container is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 1.0 GB of 1 GB physical memory used; 2.8 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
```

Then I changed the 2 parameters regarding memory to both `2 GB`. The error of container disappear now, but when I rerun the tasks in parallel, it becomes very slow and usage of CPU on all nodes are only **`1%-5%`**....

Why there are such hugh usage difference? How to increase the CPU usage and memory usage?

Comment: How many containers are running simultaneously in both cases? Check running container logs in both cases and check what is it doing

Comment: and what about cluster memory usage in case of increased size containers? It can be that simply less containers are running simultaneously because of not enough memory for them to start simultaneously. To answer this question we need all the details which you omitted.